# ToString Conversion Truncating SqlString Value in SQL CLR

Tags: c#, sql-server, tostring, sqldatatypes, sqlclr

I'm using C# to build a SQL Server CLR procedure. In that I'm trying to convert a `SqlString` parameter to string, but the result is being truncated.

Here's simplified version of the code. The parameter "MyParam" contains a string of over 200 characters, but for some reason the `ToString()` truncates it to 100 characters. Any ideas? Or better way to convert the `SqlString` parameter.

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void MySqlClrProcedure(SqlString MyParam)
{
    SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Test: " + MyParam.ToString());
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: Please show your SQL Server SP definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to always use the `Value` property of the `Sql*` types. In your case it would be: `MyParam.Value`. The `Value` property is available in all of the `Sql*` types and returns the expected .NET type.
2. There is no inherent truncation in `SqlString` as it can support `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. And `SqlContext.Pipe.Send()` should be limited to 4000 UTF-16 characters (8000 bytes) as it is a `PRINT` statement.

   Most likely your T-SQL wrapper object has its input parameter defined as `NVARCHAR(100)`. Change it to be `NVARCHAR(4000)` or even `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. If you are using Visual Studio / SSDT to build this, you can added a `SqlFacet` decorator to your input parameter to have it use that max length: `MySqlClrProcedure([SqlFacet(MaxLength=4000)] SqlString MyParam)`

To learn more about working with SQLCLR in general, please check out the series I am writing on this topic:

[Stairway to SQLCLR](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairways/stairway-to-sqlclr)

Also: [SQLCLR Info](https://SQLCLR.org/?ref=so_57899082)